# Excel VBA UserForm locking up sheet

Tags: excel, userform, vba

Hello and good morning,

I am new to Excel and VBA but am working on a spreadsheet that will greatly assist me in what I do. I have a button "btnQuery" that when pressed, should do a few things:

1. Turn off calculations
2. Perform 2 queries
3. Update pivot charts
4. Turn on calculations

It was great and working fine, until I decided to add in a progress bar. I'm working off an example from here: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/displaying_a_progress_indicator/

My intention is to make it so that the bar updates:
1. 5% before turn off calculations
2. 5% after turn off calculations
3. 35% after first query
4. 35% after second query
5. 15% after pivot updates
6. 5% after turn on calculations

However, whenever I "Show" the userform, it just locks up my page until I exit out of it. Here is the code that I have that will hopefully help:

```
Sub btnQuery_Click()
Userform1.Show
Call code.calcturnoff
Call code.data
Call code.pivot
Call code.calcturnon
End Sub
```

I currently have no code for the userform. Can anybody please offer some advice?

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're waiting for input. Make sure you open it as a non-modal dialog:

```
Userform1.Show vbModeless
```

Comment: This is the second time you've answered a question of mine. Thanks!